# Проблема с кодировкой при парсинге страницы

Tags: c#, кодировка, парсер

Пытаюсь распарсить страницу и она мне выдает иероглифы. Кодировка в заголовке указана 1251.

```
string url = "http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/4493566/?from=prt_xml_facet";     
var web = new HtmlWeb();
var document = web.Load(url);
var div_inner_text = document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='bItemCompositionLink']").InnerText;
textBox1.Text = div_inner_text;
```

Как мне указать кодировку в данном примере? Чтобы текст читался

Comment: Я рекомендую использовать Nsoup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решил проблему вебклиентом

```
  string url = "http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/4493566/?from=prt_xml_facet";
    WebClient wc = new WebClient();
    string str = wc.DownloadString(url);
    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument htmlDocument = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
    htmlDocument.LoadHtml(str);
    var div_inner_text = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='bItemCompositionLink']").InnerText;
    textBox1.Text = div_inner_text;
```

Answer (score 2):

Как указано в [этом ответе](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7883713/276994), для новых версий HtmlAgilityPack (вы пользуетесь им, правильно?) можно указать свою кодировку так:

```
var web = new HtmlWeb()
{
    AutoDetectEncoding = false,
    OverrideEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(какая там вам надо)
};
var document = web.Load(url);
// и т. д.
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот функция оп переводу строки win1251 в UTF-8. Взято [отсюда](https://forum.antichat.ru/threads/256024/).

```
private string Win1251ToUTF8(string source)
{
    Encoding utf8    = Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");
    Encoding win1251 = Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1251");

    byte[] utf8Bytes = win1251.GetBytes(source);
    byte[] win1251Bytes = Encoding.Convert(win1251, utf8, utf8Bytes);
    source = win1251.GetString(win1251Bytes);
    return source;

}
```